# How to access the "marked" build status from within a Jenkins build Groovy script

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I have seen solutions that show you how to access the current result via `manager.build.result`.  However, I have an NUnit publisher configured that marks the build as unstable or failed.  In this case, when the Groovy script runs after the NUnit plugin, the value of `manager.build.result` is still success.  Firstly, where can I find documentation on the manager.build stuff?  Secondly, how do you access the "marked" status of a build?

Answer (score 0):

That'll be why then...

```
    protected final boolean performAllBuildSteps(BuildListener listener, Iterable<? extends BuildStep> buildSteps, boolean phase) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        boolean r = true;
        for (BuildStep bs : buildSteps) {
            if ((bs instanceof Publisher && ((Publisher)bs).needsToRunAfterFinalized()) ^ phase)
                try {
                    if (!perform(bs,listener)) {
                        LOGGER.log(Level.FINE, "{0} : {1} failed", new Object[] {AbstractBuild.this, bs});
                        r = false;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    reportError(bs, e, listener, phase);
                } catch (LinkageError e) {
                    reportError(bs, e, listener, phase);
                }
        }
        return r;
    }
```

Looks like this function really usefully stores the result of each publisher in a local variable before returning the result.  So there is absolutely no way, from Groovy, to identify what the result will be when the build is finalized, without explicitly running after the build has been finalized.